# Javascript document.getElementById("id").value returning null instead of empty string when the element is an empty text box

Tags: javascript, string, dom, null

I have a text box element whose value I am trying to access using `document.getElementById("id-name").value`. I find that the call is returning a null instead of empty string. The data-type of the returned value is still string. Is null a string value?

`<input type="text" value="" id="mytext">` is the textbox whose value I am trying to fetch using `var mytextvalue = document.getElementById("mytext").value;`

Comment: @BonyT, `<input type="text" value="" id="mytext">` is the textbox whose value I am trying to fetch using `var mytextvalue = document.getElementById("mytext").value;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UVdVe/ ??? Don't see the problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting your HTML might help a bit. Instead, you can get the element first and then check if it is null or not and then ask for its value rather than just asking for the value directly without knowing if the element is visible on the HTML or not.

```
element1 = document.getElementById(id);

if(element1 != null)
{
    //code to set the value variable.
}
```

Comment: The element whose value I am trying to access is `<input type="text" value="" id="mytext">` using `document.getElementById("mytext").value` which returns a null instead of "". The element, since it is a text box is very much visible.

Answer (score 4):

fyi, this can happen if you are using the html type="number" attribute on your input tag.  Entering a non-number will clear it before your script knows what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

For your code

```
var mytextvalue = document.getElementById("mytext");
```

`mytextvalue` will contain `null` if you have a `document.write()` statement before this code. So remove the `document.write` statement and you should get a proper text object in the variable `mytextvalue`.

This is caused by `document.write` changing the document.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've omitted the value attribute in HTML markup.

Add it there as `<input value="" ... >`.

Comment: even with `value=""` null is the returned value instead of ""

Comment: Browser? I've just checked in last Opera, Chrome, FF4, IE8 and got "".

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFfEM/) and let me know if you get an alert of null value. I have copied your code there and added a couple of alerts. Just like others, I also dont see a null being returned, I get an empty string. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[**This demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJXvS/) is returning correctly for me in Chrome 14, FF3 and FF5 (with Firebug):

```
var mytextvalue = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
console.log(mytextvalue == ''); // true
console.log(mytextvalue == null); // false
```

and changing the `console.log` to `alert`, I still get the desired output in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

I think the textbox you are trying to access is not yet loaded onto the page at the time your javascript is being executed.

ie., For the Javascript to be able to read the textbox from the DOM of the page, the textbox must be available as an element. If the javascript is getting called before the textbox is written onto the page, the textbox will not be visible and so NULL is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this...    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
    var av=document.getElementById("mytext").value;
    alert(av);
    }
    </script>

    <input type="text" value="" id="mytext">
    <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="go" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using external js file add `<script src="fileName.js"></script>` at the end before closing the `</html>` tag. or place `<script>` at the end before closing html tag .