# Understanding a function returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, function, scope

This function is returning undefined and I cannot understand what's the reasoning behind it. I have a global variable:

```
var output = document.getElementById("totalNumber").value;
```

It get's the value fine, if I do a console.log I get the value inside the element.
Then I have:

```
 var add = document.getElementById("add");

 add.addEventListener("click", function(){
   console.log(adds(output));

  })

function adds(value){
  return value;
}
```

No matter what I do, it returns undefined, what is the cause?

Comment: could you please add also your HTML? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6491570/3154301 check that post

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/r63udLkr/ Without your html it is hard to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that the time you get the value of the element with id `totalNumber` to be undefined, since the input element would be empty. Normally, this selection should be done inside the callback of your event listener, since this callback needs it. For example, please check the following snippet:

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add");

add.addEventListener("click", function(){
   var output = document.getElementById("totalNumber").value;
   console.log(adds(output));
  })

function adds(value){
  return value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="totalNumber"/>
<input type="button" id="add" value="add"/>
```